# convert powershell code to read info from url to vbscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have the following code in powershell that works great but there is a need to have it run as vbscript due to .NET issues. Can anyone please help me understand call methods supported by vbscript to accomplish the following?

This code reads a URL with a method to get info using username and access key etc. $item is the placeholder for items being read.

```
$url="http://server.org/Info/svcs/Info.wsdl"
$proxy=New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $url -Class "proxy" -Namespace "Service" -UseDefaultCredential
$doc = $proxy.getPieByLogonID($UsrId,"","accesskeycodefullnumeric","authorizedusername","authorizedcomputerIP")
$Item.Info_USR_STATUS = $doc.arrayOfUser[0].USR_STATUS
```

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: What .NET issue do you have? Why wouldn't you face the same issue with vbscript?

Comment: .NET issue being that all other scripts on various servers running are vbscripts than psi or any other. There were hiccups with psi that are not yet rectified by operations so we need this effort above going with vbscript.

Comment: @NYPkgFellos That doesn't explain how its a .NET problem.